# Bind TextBox to ComboBox in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have an Access table that looks like this:

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| PartNumber | Thing1 | Thing2 | Thing3 | Item1 |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
|        123 | ABC    | XYZ    | ASD    | poi   |
|        456 | QWE    | SDF    | ERT    | lkj   |
|        789 | JKL    | IOP    | YUI    | mnb   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

I wish to create a MS Access form with a ComboBox and a TextBox like such:
[image]

Basically, I want to be able to add/edit certain fields in my table by selecting the field in the ComboBox and then setting the value of the field in the TextBox. I only, however, want to edit the Thing# fields in the table. So how would I create a macro, or VBA system, to accomplish this?

Comment: How are you populating `Thing1` in the combo box? What have you done so far?

Comment: I have attached the combobox to my table fields, so my combo box populates with all the fields in the table, So now this leads to the problem I have. How to I bind that field to the textbox, so I can add/edit it, and how can I limit the amount of fields in the combo box to just `[Thing1, Thing2, Thing3]`

Comment: Sorry, why is this question tagged with WPF? Is this solution all within MS Access?

Comment: @karfus, sorry about that, must have accidentally clicked on it. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to get you started, though you should probably want to add some additional things like validation checks and whatnot.

Firstly your form should be bound to that table you supplied us with so it makes it easier to update the data in that table. I called your table "tblThings" in my example, so whatever you call it should be in the record source property for the form:

[image]

Next, create your combobox and text field as unbound controls (i.e. just add them in from the Controls in the Design ribbon).

For your combobox, you can either use the wizard to type the values (options) you want, or you can skip the wizard and edit the combobox's properties manually like so:

[image]

Next, I'd add a button to allow you to commit your edits to the current record, and perhaps a couple of navigation buttons to go to the next/previous record.

Here's my mock-up:

[image]

The tick button will what you press when you want to commit what you put in the textbox to the Thing# field you've selected in the combo box.

The "tick" button has the following VBA in its on-click event:

```vb
Private Sub cmdApply_Click()

    Forms(frmThings).Controls(Me.cboFieldSelect) = Me.txtFieldValue

End Sub
```

Here's the "next" button's VBA to move you to the next record (again in the on-click event):

```vb
Private Sub cmdNext_Click()

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext

End Sub
```

and the "previous" button's VBA to move you to the next record (again in the on-click event):

```vb
Private Sub cmdPrev_Click()

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious

End Sub
```

So when you use the form, if you:

1. Select the "Thing" field you want to edit
2. Use the text box to give a value for the selected Thing field
3. Click the "tick" button and the value should go in to the selected Thing field

[image]

In the above example I've shown the bound fields of the form so you can see the effect working (though you don't necessarily need to have these visible on the form).

[Here's a link to my example Access file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J5B7nFljZiMVloSktpWXhzVzg/view?usp=sharing).

**Update** - alternative using combo box change event

As per comments below, here's a way to get the change event of the combo box to put the data in to your Thing fields (eliminating the need for a button to pass your data).

Switching the order of the text box and combo box, you'd enter the data in the text box first:

[image]

Then when you select the Thing field from the combo box, the data from text box will be put in the appropriate Thing field selected:

[image]

For this to work you essentially put the same VBA we had for the tick button before in the change event of the combo box (I've also emptied the text box afterwards to make it clear to the user that a new value is required for the next field they need to input):

```vb
Private Sub cboGblFieldsSelect_Change()

    Forms(frmThings).Controls(Me.cboGblFieldsSelect) = Me.txtGblFieldsValue

    Me.txtGblFieldsValue = ""

End Sub
```

[Here's the updated file for you to have a look at](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J5B7nFljZiRnRJRVhnRG5aSDQ/view?usp=sharing).

There's also a bit of validation in there that locks the combo box while the text box empty.. you may want to remove/ignore that in your project if you want to allow the use of nulls/zero-length strings.

Comment: Excellent! Works just as described. Just one question. Is there a way to have what a user enters for a item persist while they enter another item, essentially getting rid of the "tick" button"? For example, I select "Thing1" and enter "ABC" then with no "tick" button, I go to "Thing2" and so on, and when I am done with all of them, I press a global submit button. Is it possible (if not, that's fine, just one more thing to teach users).

Comment: From what you describe, Thing1's field only gets its data only after you select "Thing2" from the combobox.. when you get to Thing3 you don't have a "Thing4" to choose from so what event will get Thing3 its data?

Comment: I see what you mean, makes sense to have the "tick" button then, thanks!

Comment: on second thoughts, there is a perfectly safe way to do that. Have updated answer with an alternative below "Update".